# LTSpice: How to use .meas command to find the fundamental frequency of non-sinusoidal signal?

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, measurement, ltspice, frequency-measurement

I want to find fundamental frequency of a periodic signal (non-sinusoidal) in certain time window using the `.meas` command in LTSpice.

I was using the following code to calculate frequency (in kHz).

`.meas tran T1 find time when V(OUT)=0 rise 1000
 .meas tran T2 find time when V(OUT)=0 rise 1100
 .meas tran  Frequency param 100/(1000*(T2-T1))`

This works fine for certain cases, but when I do the parametric sweep, it gives inaccurate readings because of two issues:

Here, I assume at 1000th cycle, signal reaches its measurement window (say from time=4ms) but sometimes it doesn't. Therefor, I want to specify the absolute time for the measurement. from 4ms in this case, I have added a sample voltage waveform as below (with parametric sweep)

[image]

The zoomed waveform from 4ms is

[image]

My questions is

Is it possible to specify the starting time for the above code so that it will count cycles from the specified time? ( I tried to use `trig`-`trag` and `from`-`to` commands but failed)

Comment: If you are only interested in the harmonics, the .four command may be for you

Comment: @ PlasmaHH, Thanks, But how can we use `.four` when the fundamental frequency is unknown? Primary goal here to measure the fundamental frequency in a specified time window

Comment: It sounds a bit like mission impossible: you don't know the fundamental (ok, that's your goal), but you don't know how your circuit will behave (settling time), or how many harmonics it will have (can't rely on `.meas`). The only thing I see is to run your simulation and then `View > FFT`, and then decide which one is your fundamental, but this is not an automated process. You say you have a parametric sweep. Can't your harmonics, or anything that you can cling to, be related to the swept parameters? Some correlation?

Comment: Thanks, actually, the settling time is known. I do not care about harmonies either. Basically, I want an automated way to get an approximate value close to the fundamental from view > FFT  - for a zoomed window (e.g. from 1.4ms to 1.5ms)

Comment: @PlasmaHH,  I narrowed down the question. Would you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you know your final simulation time, and the waveforms are about settled at the end of it, so, considering what I see in your picture, you can consider 4.4ms a mark from which you can measure, like this:

```
.meas t1 find time when v(out)=0 cross=1 td=4.4m
.meas t2 find time when v(out)=0 cross=3 td=4.4m
.meas T param t2-t1
```

---

Looking more closely (the grey-ish waveform), it looks like you have skewed sines in there, which will account for harmonics, so you can't really rely on this measurement for detecting the *fundamental*, only its apparent period. Just thought I should add this.

Comment: Great! this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your signal is periodic, therefore I would expect a command like this to properly measure your fundamental period:

> .MEAS TRAN TRise TRIG when v(out) = 1.65 CROSS = 1 TARG when v(out)=1.65 CROSS=3

where: out is the name of your output pin, CROSS=1 and CROSS=3 stands for "the 1st and the 3rd time the signal crosses the specified value", in this case vdd/2 assuming vdd = 3.3V.
I use this to evaluate the propagation delay, also in .param simulations and it worked so far.

Hope this helps!
Andrea

Comment: Thanks, But this will also have the same two issues associated with my code in the question.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your question then. May I ask you to add to the question a waveform screenshot of the signal you'd like to study?

Comment: Please refer to the edited question